# How to apply Math or a function to every element in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object in js: `{x: 0, y: 0}`, and I want to increment both x and y by one. Now, this isn't a big object, so I can just use `placeholder.x` and `placeholder.y`, not very hard. But if I wanted to add more things to the object, the code would get very long and repetitive, so is there a shorter way to apply functions or math to everything in an object?

Comment: Have a look at `Object.keys()`

Comment: You can iterate over the object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) for instance.

Comment: For a better approach you can use `Object.entries()` which lists both key and value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an iterable Array of the Object's keys, then use that to loop each and perform the functions you desire:

```js
const myObject = {x: 1, y: 1};

for (key of Object.keys(myObject)) {
  myObject[key]++;
}

console.dir(myObject);
```

In production-grade code, you should check to ensure that the data you're attempting to modify is numerically-typed so you don't end up inadvertently attempting to increment a non-numeric value:

```js
const myObject = {x: 1, y: 1};

for (key of Object.keys(myObject)) {
  if (typeof myObject[key] === 'number') myObject[key]++;
}

console.dir(myObject);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, this really helped me out! I'm a js starter, so it's very cool to see this many and good answers on my question! Thank!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on an object by using `Object.keys()`:

```js
const p1 = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}

function translateXYbyN(p, n) {
  Object.keys(p).forEach((c) => p[c] = p[c] + n);
}

console.log(p1);
translateXYbyN(p1, 1);
console.log(p1);
```

Also, you can also provide a key map in order to manipulate only the wanted keys:

```js
    const p2 = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0, 
      name: "point"
    }

    function translateXYbyN(p, n, mask) {
      Object.keys(p).forEach((c) => {
        if(mask.includes(c)) 
          p[c] = p[c] + n
        });
    }

    console.log(p2);
    translateXYbyN(p2, 1, ['x','y']);
    console.log(p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function:

```js
const incObj = o => { ++o.x; ++o.y }

const placeholder = {x: 1, y: 1}

incObj( placeholder )


console.log( placeholder )
```